# WPF DataBinding Canvas with drag and drop

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a project where I have a collection of items I want to bind the Canvas to. The canvas is subclassed to provide the ability to drag and resize elements. The code to drag and resize works fine but the problem is I can't bind the canvas. I found I can do:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Items" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <controls:SuperCanvas Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
```

And the canvas is bound correctly and items appear on the Canvas. But then my subclassed canvas no longer works correctly. (resize and drag no longer function.)

Here is the code for the SuperCanvas:

```
sing System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Meld.Helpers;

namespace Meld.Controls
{
    public class SuperCanvas : Canvas
    {
        private AdornerLayer aLayer;

        private bool isDown;
        private bool isDragging;
        private double originalLeft;
        private double originalTop;
        private bool selected;
        private UIElement selectedElement;

        private Point startPoint;

        private bool locked;

        public SuperCanvas()
        {
            Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MouseLeftButtonDown += WorkspaceWindow_MouseLeftButtonDown;
            MouseLeftButtonUp += DragFinishedMouseHandler;
            MouseMove += WorkspaceWindow_MouseMove;
            MouseLeave += Window1_MouseLeave;

            PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += myCanvas_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
            PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += DragFinishedMouseHandler;
        }

        // Handler for drag stopping on leaving the window
        private void Window1_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            StopDragging();
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // Handler for drag stopping on user choice
        private void DragFinishedMouseHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            StopDragging();
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // Method for stopping dragging
        private void StopDragging()
        {
            if (isDown)
            {
                isDown = false;
                isDragging = false;
            }
        }

        // Hanler for providing drag operation with selected element
        private void WorkspaceWindow_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (locked) return;

            if (isDown)
            {
                if ((isDragging == false) &&
                    ((Math.Abs(e.GetPosition(this).X - startPoint.X) >
                      SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance) ||
                     (Math.Abs(e.GetPosition(this).Y - startPoint.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)))
                    isDragging = true;

                if (isDragging)
                {
                    Point position = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
                    SetTop(selectedElement, position.Y - (startPoint.Y - originalTop));
                    SetLeft(selectedElement, position.X - (startPoint.X - originalLeft));
                }
            }
        }

        // Handler for clearing element selection, adorner removal
        private void WorkspaceWindow_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (locked) return;

            if (selected)
            {
                selected = false;
                if (selectedElement != null)
                {
                    aLayer.Remove(aLayer.GetAdorners(selectedElement)[0]);
                    selectedElement = null;
                }
            }
        }

        // Handler for element selection on the canvas providing resizing adorner
        private void myCanvas_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //add code to lock dragging and dropping things.
            if (locked)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                return;
            }

            // Remove selection on clicking anywhere the window
            if (selected)
            {
                selected = false;
                if (selectedElement != null)
                {
                    // Remove the adorner from the selected element
                    aLayer.Remove(aLayer.GetAdorners(selectedElement)[0]);
                    selectedElement = null;
                }
            }

            // If any element except canvas is clicked, 
            // assign the selected element and add the adorner
            if (e.Source != this)
            {
                isDown = true;
                startPoint = e.GetPosition(this);

                selectedElement = e.Source as UIElement;

                originalLeft = GetLeft(selectedElement);
                originalTop = GetTop(selectedElement);

                aLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(selectedElement);
                aLayer.Add(new ResizingAdorner(selectedElement));
                selected = true;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Forgot the resizing adorner

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Meld.Helpers
{
    internal class ResizingAdorner : Adorner
    {
        // Resizing adorner uses Thumbs for visual elements.  
        // The Thumbs have built-in mouse input handling.
        Thumb topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight;

        // To store and manage the adorner's visual children.
        VisualCollection visualChildren;

        // Initialize the ResizingAdorner.
        public ResizingAdorner(UIElement adornedElement) : base(adornedElement)
        {                
            visualChildren = new VisualCollection(this);

            // Call a helper method to initialize the Thumbs
            // with a customized cursors.
            BuildAdornerCorner(ref topLeft, Cursors.SizeNWSE);
            BuildAdornerCorner(ref topRight, Cursors.SizeNESW);
            BuildAdornerCorner(ref bottomLeft, Cursors.SizeNESW);
            BuildAdornerCorner(ref bottomRight, Cursors.SizeNWSE);

            // Add handlers for resizing.
            bottomLeft.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(HandleBottomLeft);
            bottomRight.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(HandleBottomRight);
            topLeft.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(HandleTopLeft);
            topRight.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(HandleTopRight);
        }

        // Handler for resizing from the bottom-right.
        void HandleBottomRight(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs args)
        {
            FrameworkElement adornedElement = this.AdornedElement as FrameworkElement;
            Thumb hitThumb = sender as Thumb;

            if (adornedElement == null || hitThumb == null) return;
            FrameworkElement parentElement = adornedElement.Parent as FrameworkElement;

            // Ensure that the Width and Height are properly initialized after the resize.
            EnforceSize(adornedElement);

            // Change the size by the amount the user drags the mouse, as long as it's larger 
            // than the width or height of an adorner, respectively.
            adornedElement.Width = Math.Max(adornedElement.Width + args.HorizontalChange, hitThumb.DesiredSize.Width);
            adornedElement.Height = Math.Max(args.VerticalChange + adornedElement.Height, hitThumb.DesiredSize.Height);
        }

        // Handler for resizing from the top-right.
        void HandleTopRight(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs args)
        {
            FrameworkElement adornedElement = this.AdornedElement as FrameworkElement;
            Thumb hitThumb = sender as Thumb;

            if (adornedElement == null || hitThumb == null) return;
            FrameworkElement parentElement = adornedElement.Parent as FrameworkElement;

            // Ensure that the Width and Height are properly initialized after the resize.
            EnforceSize(adornedElement);

            // Change the size by the amount the user drags the mouse, as long as it's larger 
            // than the width or height of an adorner, respectively.
            adornedElement.Width = Math.Max(adornedElement.Width + args.HorizontalChange, hitThumb.DesiredSize.Width);
            //adornedElement.Height = Math.Max(adornedElement.Height - args.VerticalChange, hitThumb.DesiredSize.Height);

            double height_old = adornedElement.Height;
            double height_new = Math.Max(adornedElement.Height - args.VerticalChange, hitThumb.DesiredSize.Height);
            double top_old = Canvas.GetTop(adornedElement);
            adornedElement.Height = height_new;
            Canvas.SetTop(adornedElement, top_old - (height_new - height_old));
        }

        // Handler for resizing from the top-left.
        void HandleTopLeft(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs args)
        {
            FrameworkElement adornedElement = AdornedElement as FrameworkElement;
            Thumb hitThumb = sender as Thumb;

            if (adornedElement == null || hitThumb == null) return;

            // Ensure that the Width and Height are properly initialized after the resize.
            EnforceSize(adornedElement);

            // Change the size by the amount the user drags the mouse, as long as it's larger 
            // than the width or height of an adorner, respectively.
            //adornedElement.Width = Math.Max(adornedElement.Width - args.HorizontalChange, hitThumb.DesiredSize.Width);
            //adornedElement.Height = Math.Max(adornedElement.Height - args.VerticalChange, hitThumb.DesiredSize.Height);

            double width_old = adornedElement.Width;
            double width_new = Math.Max(adornedElement.Width - args.HorizontalChange, hitThumb.DesiredSize.Width);
            double left_old = Canvas.GetLeft(adornedElement);
            adornedElement.Width = width_new;
            Canvas.SetLeft(adornedElement, left_old - (width_new - width_old));

            double height_old = adornedElement.Height;
            double height_new = Math.Max(adornedElement.Height - args.VerticalChange, hitThumb.DesiredSize.Height);
            double top_old = Canvas.GetTop(adornedElement);
            adornedElement.Height = height_new;
            Canvas.SetTop(adornedElement, top_old - (height_new - height_old));
        }

        // Handler for resizing from the bottom-left.
        void HandleBottomLeft(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs args)
        {
            FrameworkElement adornedElement = AdornedElement as FrameworkElement;
            Thumb hitThumb = sender as Thumb;

            if (adornedElement == null || hitThumb == null) return;

            // Ensure that the Width and Height are properly initialized after the resize.
            EnforceSize(adornedElement);

            // Change the size by the amount the user drags the mouse, as long as it's larger 
            // than the width or height of an adorner, respectively.
            //adornedElement.Width = Math.Max(adornedElement.Width - args.HorizontalChange, hitThumb.DesiredSize.Width);
            adornedElement.Height = Math.Max(args.VerticalChange + adornedElement.Height, hitThumb.DesiredSize.Height);

            double width_old = adornedElement.Width;
            double width_new = Math.Max(adornedElement.Width - args.HorizontalChange, hitThumb.DesiredSize.Width);
            double left_old = Canvas.GetLeft(adornedElement);
            adornedElement.Width = width_new;            
            Canvas.SetLeft(adornedElement, left_old - (width_new - width_old));
        }

        // Arrange the Adorners.
        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            // desiredWidth and desiredHeight are the width and height of the element that's being adorned.  
            // These will be used to place the ResizingAdorner at the corners of the adorned element.  
            double desiredWidth = AdornedElement.DesiredSize.Width;
            double desiredHeight = AdornedElement.DesiredSize.Height;
            // adornerWidth & adornerHeight are used for placement as well.
            double adornerWidth = this.DesiredSize.Width;
            double adornerHeight = this.DesiredSize.Height;

            topLeft.Arrange(new Rect(-adornerWidth / 2, -adornerHeight / 2, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));
            topRight.Arrange(new Rect(desiredWidth - adornerWidth / 2, -adornerHeight / 2, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));
            bottomLeft.Arrange(new Rect(-adornerWidth / 2, desiredHeight - adornerHeight / 2, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));
            bottomRight.Arrange(new Rect(desiredWidth - adornerWidth / 2, desiredHeight - adornerHeight / 2, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));

            // Return the final size.
            return finalSize;
        }

        // Helper method to instantiate the corner Thumbs, set the Cursor property, 
        // set some appearance properties, and add the elements to the visual tree.
        void BuildAdornerCorner(ref Thumb cornerThumb, Cursor customizedCursor)
        {
            if (cornerThumb != null) return;

            cornerThumb = new Thumb();

            // Set some arbitrary visual characteristics.
            cornerThumb.Cursor = customizedCursor;
            cornerThumb.Height = cornerThumb.Width = 5;
            cornerThumb.Opacity = 0.40;
            cornerThumb.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

            visualChildren.Add(cornerThumb);
        }

        // This method ensures that the Widths and Heights are initialized.  Sizing to content produces
        // Width and Height values of Double.NaN.  Because this Adorner explicitly resizes, the Width and Height
        // need to be set first.  It also sets the maximum size of the adorned element.
        void EnforceSize(FrameworkElement adornedElement)
        {
            if (adornedElement.Width.Equals(Double.NaN))
                adornedElement.Width = adornedElement.DesiredSize.Width;
            if (adornedElement.Height.Equals(Double.NaN))
                adornedElement.Height = adornedElement.DesiredSize.Height;

            FrameworkElement parent = adornedElement.Parent as FrameworkElement;
            if (parent != null)
            {
                adornedElement.MaxHeight = parent.ActualHeight;
                adornedElement.MaxWidth = parent.ActualWidth;
            }
        }
        // Override the VisualChildrenCount and GetVisualChild properties to interface with 
        // the adorner's visual collection.
        protected override int VisualChildrenCount { get { return visualChildren.Count; } }
        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) { return visualChildren[index]; }
    }
}
```

/END EDIT

Any ideas why this doesn't work when used in the ItemsControl like above and how I could go about fixing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each item in an ItemsControl is wrapped by a ContentPresenter.  This is the element that needs to be positioned during the drag/drop operation, not the actual element contained.  You can see this is the case when you specify the ItemContainerStyle:

```
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

In the current code, the originalLeft and originalTop values are initialized using the selectedElement (whose attached properties Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top are not used to position the element) in the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event.  In the MouseMove event, the left and top values are set for the selectedElement, which has no effect because it's the ContentPresenter that must be positioned.

To fix this, the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown handler should (something like):

```
selectedElement = e.Source as UIElement;

selectedPresenter = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(selectedElement) as ContentPresenter;

originalLeft = GetLeft(selectedPresenter);
originalTop = GetTop(selectedPresenter);
```

And in the MouseMove handler, you need to use the selectedPresenter and not the selectedElement:

```
SetTop(selectedPresenter, position.Y - (startPoint.Y - originalTop));
SetLeft(selectedPresenter, position.X - (startPoint.X - originalLeft));
```

From the code you posted, I couldn't tell how you were populating the ItemsControl or what you were populating it with.  In order to test this myself, I had an ObservableCollection bound to the ItemsControl.ItemsSource property and an ItemsControl.ItemTemplate as specified below:

```
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Blue"></Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Since the data template was a FrameworkElement with a Width and Height property, the resizing worked just fine.  However, I had to make the above changes for the drag/drop to work properly.